# Getting 'ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded' undefined error in aspx page

Tags: javascript, client-object-model

I created a test custom .aspx page in sharepoint 2010 and I want to get client object model (javascript) working on it, without loading the master page.

However when I load the page, I get this error:

```
[10:47:22.513] ReferenceError: FV4UI is not defined @ http://XXXX/_layouts/1033/core.js:2
[10:47:24.882] ReferenceError: IEnumerator is not defined @ http://XXXX_layouts/sp.runtime.js:2
[10:47:28.247] TypeError: SP.ScriptUtility is undefined @ http://XXXX/_layouts/sp.js:2
```

This is what I have so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>

<html dir="ltr" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head runat="server">
<meta name="WebPartPageExpansion" content="full" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

    <title>TEST</title>

    <%-- <SharePoint:ScriptLink ID="ScriptLink1" language="javascript" name="core.js" runat="server" /> --%>
    <%-- <SharePoint:ScriptLink language="javascript" name="SP.js" defer="true" runat="server" Localizable="false"/> --%>





</head>

<body>

    <form id="form1" runat="server">


    </form>

<script type="text/javascript" src="./includes/js/jquery/jquery-2.0.2.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/1033/core.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/MicrosoftAjax.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/1033/init.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/sp.runtime.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/sp.js"></script>
<!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/sp.taxonomy.js"></script> -->


    <script type="text/javascript">
        // occurs when the document is ready
        $(document).ready(function() {
            alert(1);
            // wait for the sharepoint javascript libraries to load, then call the function 'Initialize'
            ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(runCode, "sp.js");

            alert(2);
        });


        var listItems;                   // The list of retrieved items.
        var query;                       // For paging, reuse the same query object.
        var targetList;                  // The list from which to retrieve items.
        var clientContext;

        function runCode() {
            clientContext = new SP.ClientContext();
            web = clientContext.get_web();  
            targetList = web.get_lists().getByTitle("Documents");
            query = new SP.CamlQuery();

            var CAML = "<View><Query><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Modified' Ascending='FALSE' /></OrderBy></Query></View>";
            var CS = "Include(Title,FileRef)";

            //Specifying the RowLimit will determine how many items will be fetched in one call to the server.
            query.set_viewXml(CAML);
            listItems = targetList.getItems(query);
            clientContext.load(listItems,CS);
            clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded),Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
        }

        function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {
            var message = "Titles, two at a time:\n";
            var listEnumerator = listItems.getEnumerator();
            while (listEnumerator.moveNext()) {
                message += "\nTitle=" + listEnumerator.get_current().get_item("Title")
            }
            alert(message);

            //Gets the id of the last element from the returned collection along with the query.
            var position = listItems.get_listItemCollectionPosition();
            //Position will be null if all the items in the collection are fetched and there are no more items to be fetched.
            if (position != null) {
                //If more items are to be fetched, make a second call to the server and fetch the next group of items.
                query.set_listItemCollectionPosition(position);
                listItems = targetList.getItems(query);
                clientContext.load(listItems);
                //Call the same function recursively until all the items in the current criteria are fetched.
                clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded),Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
            } 
        }

        function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
            alert('Request failed. \nError: ' + args.get_message() + '\nStackTrace: ' + args.get_stackTrace());
        }
    </script>




</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was able to get the sample running that you referenced in http://allthatjs.com/2012/04/03/using-sharepoint-csom-in-html5-apps - with a few changes.

Note the form digest, and all five javascript files must be referenced in this order. Also note the site URL is explicitly given. Using get_current will not work.  And the URL must be in the current site collection.

Here's my version, which incorporates one of the simple code examples given in the link.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<%@ Page language="C#" %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="SharePoint" 
     Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" 
     Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint" %>
<html>
<head>
    <!-- the following 5 js files are required to use CSOM -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/1033/init.js"></script>
    <script  type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/MicrosoftAjax.js"></script>
    <script  type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/sp.core.js"></script>
    <script  type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/sp.runtime.js"></script>
    <script  type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/sp.js"></script>

   <script type="text/javascript">
 // define a ClientContext for the specified SP site
var ctx = new SP.ClientContext("/sites/theSite"); 
//passing url explicitly to client context. and the url must be in the current site collection
// attach a onRequestFailed function to the client context.
ctx.add_requestFailed(function (sender, args) {
    alert('Request failed: ' + args.get_message());
});

function example () {
    var web = ctx.get_web();

    ctx.load(web);
    ctx.executeQueryAsync(function () {
        alert("Title: " + web.get_title());
        alert("Description: " + web.get_description());
    });
};

window.onload = example;

   </script>

</head>
<body>
    <SharePoint:FormDigest ID="FormDigest1" runat="server"></SharePoint:FormDigest>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your a life saver.

Comment: Evidently this doesn't work in SharePoint Online (403 forbidden). If I find a solution I'll come back and update my answer.

Comment: Get a 404 error for the Microsoft AJAX